# Floating elements within a div, floats outside of div. Why?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Say you have a `div`, give it a definite `width` and put elements in it, in my case an `img` and another `div`.

The idea is that the content of the container `div` will cause the container `div` to stretch out, and be a background for the content. But when I do this, the containing `div` shrinks to fit the non-floating objects, and the floating objects will be either all the way out, or half out, half in, and not have any bearing on the size of the big `div`.

Why is this? Is there something I'm missing, and how can I get floated items to stretch out the `height` of a containing `div`?

Answer (score 464, accepted):

The easiest is to put `overflow:hidden` on the parent div and don't specify a height:

```css
#parent { overflow: hidden }
```

Another way is to also float the parent div:

```css
#parent { float: left; width: 100% }
```

Another way uses a clear element:

```
<div class="parent">
   <img class="floated_child" src="..." />
   <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
span.clear { clear: left; display: block; }
```

Comment: It works, but now I'm twice as confused: is there an explanation for this or is this just how it is?

Comment: Yes, there is an explanation but I have since forgotten it :( Its just how it is. The `overflow:hidden` forces the browser the best it can to contain the child elements of the parent. Thats why it fixes it.

Comment: I think explanation for `overflow: hidden` is here: [link](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/). And thanks alot, it worked for me

Comment: @DavidR The easiest explanation is that html/css is a dated, poorly thought out, and poorly implemented piece of technology. In fact, this reasoning actually explains a lot of html/css quirks you've no doubt encountered since you made this post.

Comment: This answer offers nothing in terms of an explanation, which is 90% of the question.

Comment: Keep in mind that `overflow: hidden` will just hide any part of an element which flow out of the parent container. For me, this caused certain bits of text to become unreadable.

Comment: overflow: hidden and auto both worked for me but here the difference between these two.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

hidden - The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible.
auto - If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content

Comment: @VikasArora's link is broken but I think this is another link to the same article: [The magic of “overflow: hidden”](https://colinaarts-com.herokuapp.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden)

Comment: @ChrisW link is also broken on your end, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow this one may keep working

Comment: Here's Colin Aarts' article on Wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20160331194800/http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

Answer (score 188):

## Reason

The problem is that floating elements are [out-of-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23):

> An element is called *out of flow* if it is floated, absolutely
>   positioned, or is the root element.

Therefore, they don't impact surrounding elements as an [in-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x24) element would.

This is explained in [9.5 Floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

[image]

```css
html {
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-sibling {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.block-sibling:after {
  content: 'Block sibling';
  color: green;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 90px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.float:after {
  content: 'Float';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="block-sibling">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor.
</div>
```

This is also specified in [10.6 Calculating heights and margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins). For ["normal" blocks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#normal-block),

> Only children in the normal flow are taken into account (i.e.,
>   floating boxes and absolutely positioned boxes are ignored […])

[image]

```css
html {
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-parent {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
.block-parent:after {
  content: 'Block parent';
  color: blue;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 130px;
  width: 150px;
}
.float:after {
  content: 'Float';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-parent">
  <div class="float"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit.
</div>
```

## Hacky solution: clearance

A way to solve the problem is forcing some in-flow element to be placed below all floats. Then, the height of the parent will grow to wrap that element (and thus the floats too).

This can be achieved using [the `clear` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control):

> This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may *not*
>   be adjacent to an earlier floating box.

[image]

```css
html {
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-parent {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
.block-parent:after {
  content: 'Block parent';
  color: blue;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 84px;
  width: 150px;
}
.float:after {
  content: 'Float';
  color: red;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  height: 37px;
  border: 3px dashed pink;
}
.clear:after {
  position: static;
  content: 'Block sibling with clearance';
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-parent">
  <div class="float"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra.
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

So a solution is adding an empty element with `clear: both` as the last sibling of the floats

```html
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

However, that is not semantic. So better generate a [pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements) at the end of the parent:

```css
.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

There are multiple variants of this approach, e.g. using the deprecated single colon syntax `:after` to support old browsers, or using other [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-level) displays like `display: table`.

## Solution: BFC roots

There is an exception to the problematic behavior defined at the beginning: if a block element establishes a [Block Formatting Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (is a BFC root), then it will also wrap its floating contents.

According to [10.6.7 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height),

> If the element has any floating descendants whose bottom margin edge
>   is below the element's bottom content edge, then the height is
>   increased to include those edges.

[image]

```css
html {
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-parent {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
.block-parent.bfc-root:after {
  content: 'BFC parent';
  color: blue;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 127px;
  width: 150px;
}
.float:after {
  content: 'Float';
  color: red;
}
.bfc-root {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-parent bfc-root">
  <div class="float"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit.
</div>
```

Additionally, as explained [9.5 Floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats), BFC roots are also useful because of the following:

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting
>   context […] must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same
>   block formatting context as the element itself.

[image]

```css
html {
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-sibling {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.block-sibling.bfc-root:after {
  content: 'BFC sibling';
  color: green;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 90px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.float:after {
  content: 'Float';
  color: red;
}
.bfc-root {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="block-sibling bfc-root">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur.
</div>
```

A block formatting context is established by

- Block boxes with [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) other than `visible`, e.g. `hidden`

  ```css
  .bfc-root {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* display: block; */
  }
  ```
- Block containers that are not block boxes: when [`display`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop) is set to `inline-block`, `table-cell` or `table-caption`.

  ```css
  .bfc-root {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ```
- Floating elements: when [`float`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position) is set to `left` or `right`.

  ```css
  .bfc-root {
    float: left;
  }
  ```
- Absolutely positioned elements: when [`position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position) is set to `absolute` or `fixed`.

  ```css
  .bfc-root {
    position: absolute;
  }
  ```

Note those may have undesired collateral effects, like clipping overflowing content, calculating auto widths with the [shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) algorithm, or becoming out-of-flow. So the problem is that it's not possible to have an in-flow block-level element with visible overflow that establishes a BFC.

[Display L3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/) addresses these issues:

> Created the [`flow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-flow) and [`flow-root`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-flow-root) [inner display
>   types](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#inner-display-type) to better express flow layout [display types](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#display-type) and to
>   create an explicit switch for making an element a [BFC](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#bfc) root.
>   (This should eliminate the need for hacks like `::after { clear: both; }` and [`overflow: hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow) […])

Sadly, there is no browser support yet. Eventually we may be able to use

```css
.bfc-root {
  display: flow-root;
}
```

Comment: So floated boxes aren't recognized by their parent containers, hence the height collapse, but are recognized by their siblings, hence the clearfix?

Comment: @symlink Yes, parent containers don't grow to enclose floats, unless they are BFC roots. Siblings which are not BFC roots are not directly affected by blocks (but their line boxes are). However, clearance moves them below any previous float.

Comment: "Siblings which are not BFC roots are not directly affected by blocks (but their line boxes are)." - Can you clarify this please? Do you mean that In this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aggL3Lk7/2/, the floated inline image is not affecting the span (hence the span's border underlaps it) but the image is affecting the text (which is the line box) as is shown by the fact that the text is not underlapping the image?

Comment: @symlink Yes, exactly. Well, in your fiddle the border belongs to the parent, but it would be basically the same for siblings: https://jsfiddle.net/aggL3Lk7/3/

Comment: I concur.  This should be the accepted answer.  It's interesting to me that the W3 is calling the way we are forced to code a "hack".  Somebody screwed up bad.

Comment: Update 2021. display: flow-root; works now and it seems to be supported in firefox and chrome at least. Maybe the answer needs updating.

Answer (score 25):

Here's more modern approach:

```
.parent {display: flow-root;}
```

No more clearfixes.

p.s. Using overflow: hidden; hides the box-shadow so...

Comment: Works in Safari 11 as well

Answer (score 23):

Put your floating `div(s)` in a `div` and in CSS give it `overflow:hidden;`
it will work fine.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't solve me issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329349/how-to-align-div-inside-another-div?noredirect=1#comment39486464_25329349

Answer (score 23):

W3Schools recommendation:

put `overflow: auto` on parent element and it will "color" whole background including elements margins. Also floating elements will stay inside of border.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_clearfix

Answer (score 13):

Thank you **LSerni** you solved it for me.

To achieve this :

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| +-------+                     +-------+ |
| | Text1 |                     | Text2 | |
| +-------+                     +-------+ |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

You have to do this :

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
    <div style="display:inline-block;float:left"> Text1 </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;float:right"> Text2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clean, concise, and under-voted!

Answer (score 12):

In some cases, i.e. **when (if)** you're just using `float` to have elements flow on the same "line", you might use

```
display: inline-block;
```

instead of

```
float: left;
```

Otherwise, using a `clear` element at the end works, even if it may go against the grain to need an element to do what should be CSS work.

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing missing. Float was designed for the case where you want an image (for example) to sit beside several paragraphs of text, so the text flows around the image. That wouldn't happen if the text "stretched" the container. Your first paragraph would end, and then your next paragraph would begin under the image (possibly several hundred pixels below).

And that's why you're getting the result you are.

Comment: How does that have anything to do with the floated element properly stretching the height of the parent?

Answer (score 5):

As Lucas says, what you are describing is the intended behaviour for the float property. What confuses many people is that float has been pushed well beyond its original intended usage in order to make up for shortcomings in the CSS layout model.

Have a look at [Floatutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) if you'd like to get a better understanding of how this property works.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do with first you can make the div flex and apply justify content right or left and your problem is solved.

```html
<div style="display: flex;padding-bottom: 8px;justify-content: flex-end;">
     <button style="font-weight: bold;outline: none;background-color: #2764ff;border-radius: 3px;margin-left: 12px;border: none;padding: 3px 6px;color: white;text-align: center;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;text-decoration: none;margin-right: 14px;">Sense</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions here didn't work for me—my elements kept getting cut off. But if anyone else comes here using bootstrap, it worked for me to explicitly set the X-axis margins of an intermediary row div to zero and also set justify-content-between:

```
<div class='container p-2'>
  <div class='row mx-0 justify-content-between'>
    <div class='float-left'></div>
    <div class='float-right'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```