# How to create a horizontal list without "display:inline;" or "float:left;"? (Or any other fix that may work for this)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the list of links to stay in the bordered box. Using `display:inline;` results in the link boxes looking strange. Here's how it looks now

https://jsfiddle.net/9jtxjb1s/4/

The code: 
Html

```
<body>
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="LayoutDiv1">
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  
                <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="gallery1.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="gallery2.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="link3.html">Link 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="gallery3.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="link4.html">Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
            <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; Test</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

The main, relavent styling css (full copy of css on fiddle)

```
#container{
    background:#228b22;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    width:100%;
}

body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:90%;
    margin:20px auto;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:1.4em;
/*  width:98%; */
    background:white;
}

header, section, article, footer,  nav{
    padding:10px 20px 20px;
    margin:10px;
    /* float:left; */
    width:auto;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}

header {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
}

nav {
    /* float:left; */
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}

nav ul{
    margin-left:15%;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
}

nav ul li{

    float:left;
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#4ea24e;
    border:1px solid #000000;

}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

nav ul li li{
    background:#4ea24e;
    color:#fff;
    display:none;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-17.9%;
}

nav ul li li:hover{
    background:#7ab97a;
}

nav ul li li a{
    text-decoration:#8A5C2E;
    color:#black;
}

ul{
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:40%;
    padding:0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Floats can result in elements outside their containers; sometimes you need to add extra properties to avoid that behavior (e.g. [floating stuff within a div, floats outside of div. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062258/floating-stuff-within-a-div-floats-outside-of-div-why)). Regarding your code, you only need to remove the `float` and make the elements `display` as `inline-block`.

That is:

```
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;

    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#4ea24e;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

Working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avogWb

PS: Sorry I posted a codepen, I'm having issues entering the JSFiddle site.

Comment: I don't mind the codepen, I'm grateful for the help :) But like the other solutions, this results in little gaps between each box... I'm trying to keep then together

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'm glad you found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your stylesheet:

```
    #container > nav > ul {
        display: flex;
        -webkit-display: flex;

        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;

        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
    }
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ddk3bgk/)

Comment: I like this solution but when I resize the window, text no longer fits in the box

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css to fix the float problem

```
ul:after{
    content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It's almost right but this way, there are gaps between each box/list item

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `float:left`, you can make a horizontal list of links using the below css.

```
nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    font-size:0;
}
nav ul li{
    font-size: 14px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9jtxjb1s/6/

Comment: I took a look and this almost achieves the effect I want, only thing is that there is a small gap between each box

Comment: Yes, the gap is due to the font-size of parent `<ul>` element. Edited the answer and the JSFiddle link.