# why do inputs created by javascript appear outside their divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

Why are the inputs created by JavaScript in this very simple code appearing below the div instead of inside it?

HTML:

```
<div id="magicButtonDiv">
    <p>I am filler text</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function makeButton() //Activated when a button in another part of the page is pressed
{
    var text = "";
    text += "<p>What is your gender?</p>";
    text += "<input type='button' class='genderButton' value='male' onClick='maleFunction'/>";
    text += "<input type='button' class='genderButton' value='female' onClick='femaleFunction'/>";
    document.getElementById("magicButtonDiv").innerHTML=text;
}
```

CSS:

```
#magicButtonDiv
{
    box-sizing         : border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing    : border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing : border-box;
    border             : 1px solid #000000;
}

input.genderButton
{
    float.      : left;
    margin-left : 2%;
    width       : 47%;
}
```

There's more code, but I think the error is somewhere in this part of the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [floating stuff within a div, floats outside of div. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062258/floating-stuff-within-a-div-floats-outside-of-div-why)

Comment: you have many errors in your javascript..could you please add a working fiddle too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add style rule of `float:left` to your `#magicbuttondiv`. It will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3e6nw350/)

You have many errors in your Javascript. Please replace your Javascript with the below given one

```
function makeButton() {
    var text = "";
    text += "<p>What is your gender?</p>";
    text += "<input type='button' class='genderButton' value='male' onClick='maleFunction()'>";
    text += "<input type='button' class='genderButton' value='female' onClick='femaleFunction()'>";
    document.getElementById("magicButtonDiv").innerHTML = text;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just found that you have errors in your CSS too..

Notice `float.: left;` specified for `input.genderButton`. Realised just now that the float was not actually applied.

So here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3e6nw350/1/) with floats applied.

Comment: That's not the problem, I just typed it wrong when I was putting it into StackOverflow, but thanks anyways.