# Why absolute parent get child height while relative parent doesn't?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I observed the behaviour that absolutely positioned parent will set its own height to cover child elements, while relatively positioned parent doesn't. I have created 2 jsfiddles to emulate this:

Absolute:
https://jsfiddle.net/kc1g7v9s/

Relative:
https://jsfiddle.net/smy5q8Ld/

When inspect element on rendered result, the absolute-container div's dimension is 220x60, whereas relative-container div's dimension is 689x0.

Why so? I'm not particularly trying to achieve anything, just curious on the behaviour.

Code attached:

**Absolute:**

```
<div class="absolute-container">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>

.child1, .child2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.child1 {
    float: left;
}

.child2 {
    float: right;
}

.absolute-container {
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
}
```

**Relative:**

```
<div class="relative-container">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>

.child1, .child2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.child1 {
    float: left;
}

.child2 {
    float: right;
}

.relative-container {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32301823/1529630), floats are ignored when [calculating the height of "normal" blocks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#normal-block):

> Only children in the normal flow are taken into account (i.e.,
>   floating boxes and absolutely positioned boxes are ignored […])

[image]

And `position: relative` does not change this.

However, `position: absolute` produces a [Block Formatting Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). [For those](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height),

> If the element has any floating descendants whose bottom margin edge
>   is below the element's bottom content edge, then the height is
>   increased to include those edges.

[image]