# Better approach for User Profile bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently stuck with a small issue here. I have used a mark-up like this:

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".more-options").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".user-profile").toggleClass("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
/* Reset */
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-size: 12pt;}
a {text-decoration: none;}

/* Main CSS */
.user-profile {border: 1px solid #999; overflow: hidden; position: relative; margin: 25px 0;}
.user-profile .user-thumb {border: 1px solid #999; margin: 5px; padding: 3px; border-radius: 3px; float: left;}
.user-profile p:first-child {margin: 3px 0 0;}
.user-profile .more-options {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: 100%; width: 30px; background: center center no-repeat #ccc; text-indent: -99px; overflow: hidden;}
.user-profile .more-options-list {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 70px; border: 1px solid #999; width: 100px; display: none; background-color: #fff;}
.user-profile .more-options-list li, .user-profile .more-options-list li a {display: block;}
.user-profile .more-options-list li a {padding: 5px;}
.user-profile.open .more-options-list {display: block;}
.user-profile.open .more-options, .user-profile .more-options:hover {background-color: #999;}

/* Testing Sizes */
.user-profile.default {width: 250px;}
.user-profile.mobile {width: auto;}
.user-profile.large {width: 500px;}
.user-profile.small {width: 100px;}

/* Background Image, Can be ignored. */
.user-profile .more-options {background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="user-profile default">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="user-profile mobile">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="user-profile large">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="user-profile small">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Problem**

I am trying to design a **User Profile Bar**, which when live, it should be this way:

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve here, when the button is clicked. And also what happens is, the menu doesn't get displayed, because I have used `overflow: hidden;` to clear the `float`s. The menu is hidden inside.

[image]

I would like that to be responsive (well, just using percentages of `width` in different screen resolutions and instances), I would like them to display this way:

[image]

[image]

Is there a better way to achieve it? Also I am not sure how I could make the ellipsis to show, if the size is too small, see the `mobile` class in the snippet.

**Preview**

For those, who cannot preview the snippet, it would display this way:

Default view.

[image]

Arrow has been clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `position`ing for this case. This is a case of **Fixed-Fluid Model**:

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Or

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
|       | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

To tackle this, you need to make the `fixed` content to be positioned `absolute` and I guess, being a fixed content, you will surely know the dimensions. And give the parent `position: relative` and a `padding-left` and `min-height` of those dimensions. You should **never** use `overflow: hidden` or `float`s in this case. So remove both from your CSS and make these changes:

```css
.user-profile {border: 1px solid #999; position: relative; margin: 25px 0;} /* Remove overflow: hidden; */
.user-profile .user-thumb {border: 1px solid #999; margin: 5px; padding: 3px; border-radius: 3px;} /* Remove float: left; */
```

Instead, as said before, add `padding`, `min-height` for the parent and `position: absolute` for the child:

```css
.user-profile {border: 1px solid #999; position: relative; margin: 25px 0; padding-left: 68px; min-height: 68px;}
.user-profile .user-thumb {border: 1px solid #999; margin: 5px; padding: 3px; border-radius: 3px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

**The mysterious `68px`:**

The `68px` is calculated by this way:

- Left Margin: `5px`
- Left Border: `1px`
- Left Padding: `3px`
- Width: `50px`
- Right Padding: `3px`
- Right Margin: `1px`
- Right Border: `5px`

So, `5px + 1px + 3px + 50px + 3px + 1px + 5px = 68px`.

**Text Ellipsis**

For the ellipsis to work on major browsers, you can use the following code:

```css
(selector) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Just add this to the `.user-profile p` rule:

```css
.user-profile p {white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;}
```

Also, it is always better to have a `z-index` in place for `position: absolute` items to work well with other similar items. So please add:

```css
.user-profile .more-options-list {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 70px; border: 1px solid #999; width: 100px; display: none; background-color: #fff; z-index: 1;}
```

So, the final code would be:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".more-options").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".user-profile").toggleClass("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
/* Reset */
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-size: 12pt;}
a {text-decoration: none;}

/* Main CSS */
.user-profile {border: 1px solid #999; position: relative; margin: 25px 0; padding-left: 68px; min-height: 68px;}
.user-profile .user-thumb {border: 1px solid #999; margin: 5px; padding: 3px; border-radius: 3px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
.user-profile p {white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;}
.user-profile p:first-child {margin: 3px 0 0;}
.user-profile .more-options {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: 100%; width: 30px; background: center center no-repeat #ccc; text-indent: -99px; overflow: hidden;}
.user-profile .more-options-list {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 70px; border: 1px solid #999; width: 100px; display: none; background-color: #fff; z-index: 1;}
.user-profile .more-options-list li, .user-profile .more-options-list li a {display: block;}
.user-profile .more-options-list li a {padding: 5px;}
.user-profile.open .more-options-list {display: block;}
.user-profile.open .more-options, .user-profile .more-options:hover {background-color: #999;}

/* Testing Sizes */
.user-profile.default {width: 250px;}
.user-profile.mobile {width: auto;}
.user-profile.large {width: 500px;}
.user-profile.small {width: 100px;}

/* Background Image, Can be ignored. */
.user-profile .more-options {background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="user-profile default">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="user-profile mobile">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="user-profile large">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="user-profile small">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Preview**

This is how it appears with and without the menu open.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps you to achieve what you want.

Comment: How did you get the `68px` for the `padding-left` and `min-height`?

Comment: @VennilaSundarRajan Okay I will explain it in my answer.

Comment: @VennilaSundarRajan Is this fine?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't want to hide the overflow, you want to establish a Block Formatting Context. And yes, `overflow: hidden` establishes a BFC as a side effect, but that's just a hack. In CSS2.1 there are other ways of establishing a BFC, but all have its own problems, like taking out-of-flow, becoming inline-level, ...

Display L3 introduces a proper way of establishing BFCs:

```css
display: flow-root;
```

But browsers don't support it yet. So meanwhile, I recommend clearance hacks:

```css
.wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```js
$(function () {
  $(".more-options").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".user-profile").toggleClass("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.user-profile:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
/* Reset */
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-size: 12pt;}
a {text-decoration: none;}

/* Main CSS */
.user-profile {border: 1px solid #999; position: relative; margin: 25px 0;}
.user-profile .user-thumb {border: 1px solid #999; margin: 5px; padding: 3px; border-radius: 3px; float: left;}
.user-profile p:first-child {margin: 3px 0 0;}
.user-profile .more-options {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: 100%; width: 30px; background: center center no-repeat #ccc; text-indent: -99px; overflow: hidden;}
.user-profile .more-options-list {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 70px; border: 1px solid #999; width: 100px; display: none; background-color: #fff;}
.user-profile .more-options-list li, .user-profile .more-options-list li a {display: block;}
.user-profile .more-options-list li a {padding: 5px;}
.user-profile.open .more-options-list {display: block;}
.user-profile.open .more-options, .user-profile .more-options:hover {background-color: #999;}

/* Testing Sizes */
.user-profile.default {width: 250px;}
.user-profile.mobile {width: auto;}
.user-profile.large {width: 500px;}
.user-profile.small {width: 100px;}

/* Background Image, Can be ignored. */
.user-profile .more-options {background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABEAAAALCAYAAACZIGYHAAAEJGlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAOBGFVd9v21QUPolvUqQWPyBYR4eKxa9VU1u5GxqtxgZJk6XtShal6dgqJOQ6N4mpGwfb6baqT3uBNwb8AUDZAw9IPCENBmJ72fbAtElThyqqSUh76MQPISbtBVXhu3ZiJ1PEXPX6yznfOec7517bRD1fabWaGVWIlquunc8klZOnFpSeTYrSs9RLA9Sr6U4tkcvNEi7BFffO6+EdigjL7ZHu/k72I796i9zRiSJPwG4VHX0Z+AxRzNRrtksUvwf7+Gm3BtzzHPDTNgQCqwKXfZwSeNHHJz1OIT8JjtAq6xWtCLwGPLzYZi+3YV8DGMiT4VVuG7oiZpGzrZJhcs/hL49xtzH/Dy6bdfTsXYNY+5yluWO4D4neK/ZUvok/17X0HPBLsF+vuUlhfwX4j/rSfAJ4H1H0qZJ9dN7nR19frRTeBt4Fe9FwpwtN+2p1MXscGLHR9SXrmMgjONd1ZxKzpBeA71b4tNhj6JGoyFNp4GHgwUp9qplfmnFW5oTdy7NamcwCI49kv6fN5IAHgD+0rbyoBc3SOjczohbyS1drbq6pQdqumllRC/0ymTtej8gpbbuVwpQfyw66dqEZyxZKxtHpJn+tZnpnEdrYBbueF9qQn93S7HQGGHnYP7w6L+YGHNtd1FJitqPAR+hERCNOFi1i1alKO6RQnjKUxL1GNjwlMsiEhcPLYTEiT9ISbN15OY/jx4SMshe9LaJRpTvHr3C/ybFYP1PZAfwfYrPsMBtnE6SwN9ib7AhLwTrBDgUKcm06FSrTfSj187xPdVQWOk5Q8vxAfSiIUc7Z7xr6zY/+hpqwSyv0I0/QMTRb7RMgBxNodTfSPqdraz/sDjzKBrv4zu2+a2t0/HHzjd2Lbcc2sG7GtsL42K+xLfxtUgI7YHqKlqHK8HbCCXgjHT1cAdMlDetv4FnQ2lLasaOl6vmB0CMmwT/IPszSueHQqv6i/qluqF+oF9TfO2qEGTumJH0qfSv9KH0nfS/9TIp0Wboi/SRdlb6RLgU5u++9nyXYe69fYRPdil1o1WufNSdTTsp75BfllPy8/LI8G7AUuV8ek6fkvfDsCfbNDP0dvRh0CrNqTbV7LfEEGDQPJQadBtfGVMWEq3QWWdufk6ZSNsjG2PQjp3ZcnOWWing6noonSInvi0/Ex+IzAreevPhe+CawpgP1/pMTMDo64G0sTCXIM+KdOnFWRfQKdJvQzV1+Bt8OokmrdtY2yhVX2a+qrykJfMq4Ml3VR4cVzTQVz+UoNne4vcKLoyS+gyKO6EHe+75Fdt0Mbe5bRIf/wjvrVmhbqBN97RD1vxrahvBOfOYzoosH9bq94uejSOQGkVM6sN/7HelL4t10t9F4gPdVzydEOx83Gv+uNxo7XyL/FtFl8z9ZAHF4bBsrEwAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAXFpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IlhNUCBDb3JlIDQuNC4wIj4KICAgPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4KICAgICAgPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIKICAgICAgICAgICAgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIj4KICAgICAgICAgPHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD5BZG9iZSBQaG90b3Nob3AgQ1M2IChXaW5kb3dzKTwveG1wOkNyZWF0b3JUb29sPgogICAgICA8L3JkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4KICAgPC9yZGY6UkRGPgo8L3g6eG1wbWV0YT4KQ+u4tgAAAVNJREFUKBV9kT9Lw1AUxfNeUxDc1N2CQ0kNDhqUbq46K4izg4PgLugHECdF6qBTcdJNxNFFVMQ6lbTQIX4BF5cI0cbfLb1SatILyb33vHPO+3NNmqaO53nVQqFQdRznpdlsPpBHhu/7i91ud85a+wg/NJVKZRtFTVWYXsRxvBNF0ZdimoMgKLJ2TC8aiW9jzIaYvNNMC6KB0Rs7rbXb7Uixcrk8xWmvEC0rJhluw/IrDoJSQ5xH8MoGq9LPEq7rPg8b9LnjluJImoyYALvB6JyNnqhnMjiy4amB4EDcgnACMJZFzMEStLthGNZ6JkJiQguYXPOVpB8ViD+YzDqTuReeXKcXrVarwWJAc9eH8lLIey2pgZD+TqIKTmK53j6GB1IrLhnsNkmSzU6n8zmI/zPRRQaygqiO0WTf4JDT7oH9KEdzrokQeKcSJpeUZzxgXUXD+RcR85AyRBGQ7AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="user-profile default">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="user-profile mobile">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="user-profile large">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="user-profile small">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="user-thumb" />
  <div class="user-profile-meta">
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Username</strong></a></p>
    <p><span>Designation</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="more-options">More Options</a>
  <ul class="more-options-list">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to know more about BFC roots, I explained them nicely [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32301823/1529630).