# Why the wrapping on Firefox, with a display: block; overflow: hidden inside a display: inline-block?

Tags: html, css

### Code

```css
#a {
  display: inline-block;
}
#b {
  float: left;
}
#c {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span id="a">
    <span id="b">b</span>
    <span id="c">c1 c2</span>
</span>
```

On Chrome and IE, this gets rendered as:

[image: Chrome]

However, Firefox renders this as:

[image: Firefox]

You can try it in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avernet/L5s1rtmz/).

### Questions

1. Why this difference? Is this a Firefox bug? (If it is, a bug, I'd be interested in the link to the bug, so I can vote for it to be fixed.)
2. How to get Firefox to render this like Chrome does, given some of the constraints mentioned in the next section?

### Context

Here is just a little bit of context, without which what I'm trying to do above might seem crazy. I intend to use the above blocks for a label, like:

[image: First name label]

The elements `#a`, `#b`, and `#c` correspond to:

[image: What the elements correspond to]

The CSS is designed to deal with the following constraints:

1. In need this to work with IE8 (no flexbox for me).
2. Block `#a` is clickable, and I don't want it to expand to the right more than is necessary, hence the `inline-block`. But obviously, another way to do the same would work.
3. The content of block `#c` must wrap if it become too long, and shouldn't go "below" block `#b`, as shown below. This explain the `overflow: hidden` or `display: table`.

[image: Long label]

Answer (score 7):

### The Fix

Don't mix, embrace the table!

"Fixes" it on Firefox (tested 31.2.0) and IE 8, and is honestly more semantically correct.

```css
.a{ display:inline-table; max-width:45%; }
.b{ display:table-cell; padding-right:5px;}
.c{ display:table-cell; }
```

```html
<span class="a">
  <span class="b">b</span>
  <span class="c">c1 c2</span>
</span>

<br /><hr /><br />

<span class="a">
  <span class="b">longer</span>
  <span class="c">Bacon ipsum dolor amet excepteur laboris irure, corned beef minim pastrami venison in anim incididunt strip steak ea non doner.</span>
</span>
```

---

### Why There Was An Issue

The problem with your original code is that Firefox takes the floated element completely out of flow when calculating its shrink-to-fit sizing. While `float`s affect in-flow content width, they themselves are not in-flow, and thus, are merely taking the horizontal space from the rest of the content- causing the behavior you were seeing

Here is a demonstration of what is happening (view in Firefox to actually see it). Note that `outline`s are used on `.a` and `.c` but a thick `border` (which actually takes up space) is used on `.b`.

```css
.a { display: inline-block; outline: 1px solid blue; }
.b { float: left; border: 5px solid green; }
.c { display: table; outline: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<span class="a">
    <span class="b">b</span>
    <span class="c">c1 c2</span>
</span>
<br />
<span class="c">c1 c2</span>
```

*This is by design, not a bug*, and checking [the current spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats), [the basic box model working draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#float), and [the spec regarding calculating widths](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) you'll find that floats are noted as out-of-flow, and [the spec regarding block-formatting and inline-formatting](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) explicitly states that `float`s are part of an inline-context width, but does not for a block-context (the inside of an `inline-block`). Thus, Firefox is actually behaving according to a strict interpretation of the spec- this is technically a bug in the other browsers.

Yet, there is still an issue with how Firefox does this.

If we make the float larger than our in-flow content (and switch back to borders as outlines include overflowing children; I've shifted the sibling red left by 1px so it will line up with its nephew clone) (again, view in Firefox)

```css
.a { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid blue; }
.b { float: left; border: 5px solid green; width:200px; }
.c { display: table; border: 1px solid red; }
.d { position:relative; left:1px; }
.e { max-width:100px; }
```

```html
<span class="a">
    <span class="b">b</span>
    <span class="c">c1 c2</span>
</span>
<br />
<span class="c d">c1 c2</span>
<br />
^^^ without <em>.a</em> having a width limit
<hr />
vvv with <em>.a</em> having a width limit
<br />
<span class="a e">
    <span class="b">b</span>
    <span class="c">c1 c2</span>
</span>
<br />
<span class="c d">c1 c2</span>
```

The blue box is stretched to contain its entire green child, even though, according to the strict interpretation of [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting), it is supposed to overflow instead. THIS is a bug with Firefox, as floats are only supposed to affect parent `width:auto` in an inline context. In a block context, which the inside of an `inline-block` is supposed to be, the width of floats is not included.

Note, this is also how most other browsers behave (to a degree- Firefox will size the parent to the `float`'s box width, while other browsers will put the in-flow next to it if the parent can still grow), and that if you provide any `width` values or limits on `.a` (ala `.e` in my example), you get the expected behavior (as shown) of the green float overflowing its parent (should be the case in all browsers, as all of these behavioral issues are based on `width:auto`).

---

### Credits

Many beers to Oriol (poster of the other answer)- if I didn't start arguing with him on this, I wouldn't've had a reason to actually get into the specs and figure out what was *really* happening. Also credit to him for pointing out Firefox did still mis-render it- that entire chunk was thanks to him.

Answer (score 0):

### What happens under the hood

1. According to [inline-block width](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width), the width of `#a` is calculated with the shrink-to-fit algorithm:

   > If [`width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) is `auto`, the used value is the [shrink-to-fit](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) width

   The [shrink-to-fit algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) (now called [fit-content measure](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#fit-content-measure)) is

   > min([max-content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#max-content), max([min-content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#min-content), [fill-available](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#fill-available)))

   This means that, if there is enough space, its width will be the maximum preferred width of the contents (that is, without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur). Otherwise, it will be as wide as the available space.
2. Then, browsers calculate the preferred width of `#a` first.

   Usually, floats overlap following block boxes, as explained in [Floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

   > Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
   >   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
   >   exist.

   Then, Firefox seems to calculate that preferred width as if `#b` and `#c` could overlap. So the preferred width is the maximum of the width of the float `#b` and the width of `#c`.

   However, `#c` establishes a new [block formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (BFC), due to `overflow: hidden`:

   > block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' [...] establish new
   >   block formatting contexts for their contents.

   In your fiddle, `#c` is a table instead, but it's the same because, as defined in [Tables model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#model),

   > The table wrapper box establishes a block formatting context.

   But as explained in [BFC next to floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#model), BFC roots can't overlap floats:

   > The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
   >   element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting
   >   context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must
   >   not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting
   >   context as the element itself.

   Instead, the float can "push" the BFC to the right. That's why on Chrome and Edge, the preferred width of `#a` is the sum of the preferred widths of `#b` and `#c`.
3. The width of `#a` will then be the preferred width calculated in the previous step in case it's not greater than the available width.

   Otherwise, browsers will calculate the preferred minimum width by introducing a line break between `#b` and `#c`. So it will be the maximum of the minimum preferred widths of `#b` and `#c`. And the final width of `#a` will be the maximum between that preferred minimum width and the available width.
4. Now the width of `#a` has been resolved, so the widths of `#b` and `#c` can be resolved too.

   Since `#b` is floated, it will be sized with the shrink-to-fit algorithm too.

   If `#c` is a block, it will take the remaining space (if there isn't available space, it will be moved to the next line). If it's a table, the default [automatic table layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout) algorithm is implementation-dependent, but similar to shrink-to-fit. The result is basically the same.

   In case of Chrome and Edge, if there was enough space, the remaining space taken by `#c` is its preferred width, because the preferred width of `#a` was the sum of `#b` and `#c`.

   However, Firefox used the maximum. Therefore, if `#b` is wider than `#c`, `#b` will fill `#a` completely, and `#c` will be moved to the next line. If `#c` is wider than `#b`, there will be some remaining space next to `#b`, so `#c` will shrink to fit there. That shrinkment causes `#c` to be smaller than its preferred width (even if `#a` has available space to grow more), so some line break will appear in `#c`.

### Summary

1. By default, a block grows to fill the available width of its containing block.
2. If there is a float smaller than the containing block, the following block will overlap it and still be as wide as the containing block.
3. But if that following block establishes a BFC, it will shrink to avoid overlapping the float, and will only fill the remaining space left by the float.
4. By default, a float or an inline-block attempts to be as wide as its contents want.

Chrome and Edge first detect the BFC root won't overlap the float, and then the width of the inline-block parent becomes the sum of the float and the BFC root.

Instead, Firefox initially sees the BFC root as a normal block, it thinks it will overlap the float, and calculates the width of the parent accordingly. Then detects it's a BFC root, prevents the overlap, and shrinks it to fit in the remaining space.

So the difference seems that they calculate the width of the parent and prevent BFC roots from overlapping floats in different order.

The incorrect behavior seems Firefox's. As defined in [Intrinsic Sizes of Non-Replaced Blocks](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#block-intrinsic), the preferred width should be calculated after layout, and most probably layout includes pushing BFC roots next to floats.

> The [max-content measure](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#max-content-measure) of a *block container box* is the
>   measure of the box after layout, if all children are sized under a
>   [max-size constraint](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#max-size-constraint).

### Fix

Using an inline-level display like `display: inline-block` or `display: inline-table` on `#c` makes Firefox sum the widths of `#b` and `#c` when calculating the width of `#a`. This way, if there is enough available space, `#c` won't shrink and no line breaks will appear.

The problem is that, in case the contents of the inline-level are too wide to fit in the remaining space left by the float, the inline-level will be moved to the next line instead of shrinking.

```css
.a { display: inline-block; }
.b { float: left;           }
.c { display: inline-table; }
```

```html
<span class="a">
  <span class="b">b</span>
  <span class="c">c1 c2</span>
</span>
<hr />
<span class="a">
  <span class="b">longer</span>
  <span class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut quis diam nec ligula iaculis lacinia non ac neque. Vivamus ut condimentum enim, et sollicitudin magna. In rhoncus nisi at est rhoncus feugiat sed vitae lacus. Maecenas sed felis et libero posuere iaculis a in lacus. Quisque eleifend auctor metus, a congue sapien venenatis a. Duis mollis mauris vitae massa mollis, nec porta nulla semper. Proin fringilla et nibh ac tempor. Aenean et augue ut dui pharetra scelerisque sed sit amet dolor. Nulla posuere a lorem sit amet vehicula. Morbi nec lacinia nibh. Suspendisse lacus nulla, dignissim et mi ut, luctus lobortis nisl. </span>
</span>
```

Alternatively, if old browser support is not a problem, you can use flexbox. A simple `#a { display: inline-flex; }` would basically work, but the following is closer to your current code.

```css
.a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow line breaks if #b is too wide */
}
.c {
  flex: 1; /* Initial width of 0, then take remaining space left by #b */
}
```

```html
<span class="a">
  <span class="b">b</span>
  <span class="c">c1 c2</span>
</span>
<hr />
<span class="a">
  <span class="b">longer</span>
  <span class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut quis diam nec ligula iaculis lacinia non ac neque. Vivamus ut condimentum enim, et sollicitudin magna. In rhoncus nisi at est rhoncus feugiat sed vitae lacus. Maecenas sed felis et libero posuere iaculis a in lacus. Quisque eleifend auctor metus, a congue sapien venenatis a. Duis mollis mauris vitae massa mollis, nec porta nulla semper. Proin fringilla et nibh ac tempor. Aenean et augue ut dui pharetra scelerisque sed sit amet dolor. Nulla posuere a lorem sit amet vehicula. Morbi nec lacinia nibh. Suspendisse lacus nulla, dignissim et mi ut, luctus lobortis nisl. </span>
</span>
```

Comment: With `display: inline-table`, the text doesn't wrap properly when it becomes longer. It gives: http://i.imgur.com/OFHfy1M.png. Try in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avernet/j6Lppaf0/).

Comment: This is what I'm doing in my original code, isn't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure if you tried, but `#c { display: block; overflow: hidden; }` and `#c { display: table }` do give the same result. I started with the `display: table`, and then tried the `display: block; overflow: hidden` as alternate way to create a BNF. But in my testing both give the same result.

Comment: @abluejelly CSS does not work like prioritizing horizontal space or vertical space. Here `#a` is sized according to the shrink-to-fit algorithm, and therefore, if there is enough space (there is), it should have the maximum width required by the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur. Firefox seems to violate this rule. What `ipsum` are you talking about?

Comment: @Oriol I've seen you edited your answer to provide more details; but you saw my first comment, re `display: inline-table` not doing wrapping properly, right?

Comment: @Oriol OK, got it :).

Comment: @Oriol And I'm right for a significantly wrong reason, wew. The issue is `float:left;` removes from document flow for the initial sizing; notice the right border lines up: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLe28epq/)

Comment: @abluejelly Yep, that's what I attempted to describe in my answer

Comment: @Oriol Not very well.... Firefox actually removes floating elements from the document flow, it's not calculating it as though `#a` and `#b` are on separate lines. Throw a bunch of `float`s in a `div` with no other content or a declared `height` then inspect it in firebug- the `div` will have a height of 0.

Comment: @abluejelly True, unless the container establishes a block formatting context. See [floating stuff within a div, floats outside of div. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32301823/1529630). Here the width of the float is not completely ignored: https://jsfiddle.net/wLe28epq/1/

Comment: @Oriol The width is completely ignored in that sample- the reason your borders don't line up is because they're `border`s. Switch them to `outline`s and they line up [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLe28epq/3/). In addition, I see nothing [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) or [the WD spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#float) that implies width of the float is actually in-flow, regardless of what the parent context is. An `inline` is STF on its in-flow content, `float` is out of flow but effects flow. Firefox is only "wrong" because other browsers do it wrong.

Comment: @abluejelly Yes, floats are technically out-of-flow. But if the width of the float were completely ignored, the float wouldn't be able to make the parent grow, but it does on Firefox. Thus the width is the float is not ignored. Should it be ignored? Well, the spec does say explicitly which contents should be taken into account for shrink-to-fit width algorithm of block formatting context roots. But it's reasonable to assume it's like height: in-flow contents and floats that participate in that block formatting context are taken into account, and absolutely positioned children are ignored.

Comment: @Oriol The float's width is not growing the width of its parent. Your demo of it was being caused by double 1px `border`s (one parent, one child) and a single 1px `border` around the sample. Check my fix to your demo using `outline`s and only a `border` on the `float`. The width of the float IS ignored for horizontal space as it is not in flow, but because it affects in-flow content and the spec _specifically states_ that in-flow content should be shifted vertically to fit, no, Firefox's behavior is what's reasonable.

Comment: @Oriol in fact, actually, [the block formatting spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) even notes that the lines may be narrower due to `float`s. Thanks for getting me to check another spec. Makes my own answer even more complete lol

Comment: @abluejelly Not sure if we are talking about the same. I mean that if the green float is wider than the red block, the blue parent grows to cover the green float. in that sense, the width of the green float is not ignored.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107250/discussion-between-abluejelly-and-oriol).