# Make an element move below a div without setting height on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="test">
  // These links are added with JavaScript
  <a href="fijf">Text 1</a>
  <a href="dfugru">Text 2</a>   
</div>
<h1>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  // Other properties
}

.test {
  display: block;
}
```

My problem is that the `div` and heading appear side by side. However, I want the heading to appear below the `div`.

I assumed that using `display:block` will solve the issue but it doesn't.
I tried adding a `<br>` tag after the `div` but that does not work either.
One thing that works is setting a height on `.test`. The problem with this is that some other users might set a higher font-size, hence,(rendering the height I set on container useless) for links somewhere else and this will mess up the layout.

EDIT:

**I have just control over the div and the elements inside it. There can be anything above or below the div. The heading is just for reference.**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5qz7y2p/)

Comment: is there a parent container with some css applied to it?

Comment: The parent container has no CSS applied.

Comment: This is a simple float clearing issue. [One common method is to clear the floats with a pseudo-element](https://jsfiddle.net/4xh066bd/).

Comment: Have you tried putting display:block on the h1 element? The element with block applied to it is usually the one that will fall to the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have two options:

- Make `.test` establish a new block formatting context, e.g. with `overflow: hidden`.

  This will make it grow vertically to include the floats, and then the floats won't affect the header because it will be below them.

  ```css
  .test {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .test {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 10px 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="test">
    <a href="fijf">Text 1</a>
    <a href="dfugru">Text 2</a>   
  </div>
  <h1>UI am header</h1>
  ```
- Clear the header. This will force it to be placed below the floats.

  ```css
  h1 {
    clear: left;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  h1 {
    clear: left;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 10px 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="test">
    <a href="fijf">Text 1</a>
    <a href="dfugru">Text 2</a>   
  </div>
  <h1>UI am header</h1>
  ```

Comment: There are so many questions that this can be listed as a duplicate of. It's a simple float clearing issue, why add yet another duplicate answer?

Comment: Thanks.I will have to go with the first one because the styling on next element is not in my control. Moreover, it may or may not be a headline.

Comment: @misterManSam I was considering voting as a dupe of [floating stuff within a div, floats outside of div. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2062258/1529630), but the objective is not exactly the same (the techniques are). I searched "prevent element from being next to float" questions but didn't find proper results.

Comment: @misterManSam I have updated the question with more detail. I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Oriol Can you please provide me a link to read more about establishing a new block formatting context? Thanks.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32301823/1529630)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:left; clear:left`

Comment: That doesn't help. Now, all the links are displayed vertically.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="test">
  <a href="fijf">Text 1</a>
  <a href="dfugru">Text 2</a>   
</div>
<h1>
UI am header
</h1>
```

CSS

```
.test {
      width:100%;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/g6rmz4x8/)

[Edited JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/L5qz7y2p/4/)

Comment: Thanks :). However, this doesn't help. See my fiddle.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh you didnt applied rules on test class. See this new fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your floats.

`.test::after { content: ''; display: table; clear: both; }`

https://jsfiddle.net/L5qz7y2p/3/