# margin left doesn't work on display flex but works on inner child how?

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

child1: side content, child2: display flex.

I need child2 to move left by 150px.

If I set `margin-left` on child2 it doesn't work.

But if I set `margin-left` on child of child2 it works.

```css
.side {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.table-wrap {
  margin-left: -150px; /* doesn't work */
}
.table {
  margin-left: -150px; /* doesn't work */
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  margin-left: -150px; /* works oyea */
}
.stuff {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="side">
    side content
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="stuff"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why? pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGwVpP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `display: inline-block` instead of `display: flex;` on `.table` element.

Comment: The cause is not the non-existence of collapsing margins in flexbox. The cause is the float.

Comment: Right, I wasn't sure about this. After reading your answer, it's more clear to me, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

That's because the float is out-of-flow, so it overlaps `.table-wrap`. But it reduces the length of line boxes inside it.

[image]

Then it seems the margin is ignored, but in fact it's not: `.table-wrap` is really moved to the left, but the contents aren't due to the float.

Instead, you should make `.table-wrap` establish a new block formatting context (BFC). Then it won't overlap the float.

[image]

For example, you can establish a BFC with `overflow: hidden`, `display: inline-block` or `float: left`. Here the former would be bad because it would hide the content overflowing due to the negative margin, so use one of the others.

```css
.side {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.table-wrap {
  display: inline-block; /* Establish Block Formatting Context */
  margin-left: -150px;   /* Now this works */
}
.table {
  display: flex;
}
.stuff {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="side">
    side content
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="stuff"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, since you are already using flexbox, you can make `.content` be a flex container instead of floating `.side`

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.side {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.table-wrap {
  margin-left: -150px; /* Now this works */
}
.table {
  display: flex;
}
.stuff {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="side">
    side content
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="stuff"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32301823/1529630) I explained BFCs with more detail.