# JQuery .height() returning 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Live: http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/index123.html#

I am trying to use JQuery to obtain the height for the amount of administrators under the users section of the quick side bar you see to the right.

```
    var temp = $('.Admins').height();
    alert(temp);
```

The above what should be working script, regardless of if I enclose within document ready or window load, always returns the value of 0 and not the height.

Comment: The div IS 0 in height as far as I can see with the inspector tool..

Comment: Before the closing tag of the .Admins div, put this code in `<div style="clear:both"></div>`, right now, because of the float of the elements inside, the parent container height is 0

Comment: Related: [floating stuff within a div, floats outside of div. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062258/floating-stuff-within-a-div-floats-outside-of-div-why) Also [Which method of ‘clearfix’ is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Comment: @DanielLisik this works perfectly. Can you submit this as an answer explaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the float style in the child elements. Try adding this code to clear the float:

```
.Group.Admins::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: [David Horák Anser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36683216/2199267) works perfectly too, don't know why this is the reason but thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

The div **Group Admins** doesn't have height. Try to add `float: left;` to Group Admins and you will get the height.