# CSS float left issue

Tags: html, css

OK so here is my code

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.div1{
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 background-color:red;
 display:block;
 float:left;
} 
.div2{
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 background-color:green;
 display:block;
 
}
.div3{
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 background-color:yellow;
 display:block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I want my website to look like this: first square is red, next to is green, and below red is yellow square. I thought that float left on first element should make next one jump right next to him. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 4):

Add `float: left;` to .div2 and `clear:left` to .div3

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.div1{
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 background-color:red;
 display:block;
 float:left;
} 
.div2{
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 background-color:green;
 display:block;
 float: left;
}
.div3{
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 background-color:yellow;
 display:block;
    clear: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

You need to add `float:left` to the green box in order to make the element stand next to red. If you added the `float:left` to the yellow square, it would stand next to green. We added `clear: left` to "clear" the left floats.

Read more about [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Comment: Yea, but why doesn't my work? When i float left first element shouldn't next one come automaticly next to him?

Comment: No, you have to add float: left to all the elements that should stand next to that element. If you want to get rid of "float" in the next element add `clear: left` (if it was `float: left`) or `clear: right` (if it was a `float: right`). If you mixed floats you can add `clear:both`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that floating elements are [out-of-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23):

> An element is called *out of flow* if it is floated, absolutely
>   positioned, or is the root element.

Therefore, they don't impact surrounding elements as an [in-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x24) element would.

This is explained in [9.5 Floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

[image]

```css
html {
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-sibling {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.block-sibling:after {
  content: 'Block sibling';
  color: green;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 90px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.float:after {
  content: 'Float';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="block-sibling">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor.
</div>
```

There is an exception to that problematic behavior: if a block element establishes a [Block Formatting Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (is a BFC root), then it won't overlap the float:

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting
>   context […] must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same
>   block formatting context as the element itself.

[image]

```css
html {
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-sibling {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.block-sibling.bfc-root:after {
  content: 'BFC sibling';
  color: green;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 90px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.float:after {
  content: 'Float';
  color: red;
}
.bfc-root {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="block-sibling bfc-root">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur.
</div>
```

For example, you can establish a BFC with [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) different than `visible`, e.g. `hidden`

```css
.div2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.div2 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div3 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Comment: See [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32301823/1529630) for more information about BFCs and the problems they solve.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the BFC Sibling but I recommend using the display:inline-block in your example. It's easier to understand cause overflow (although it is valid) but just does not make sense in the context.

Comment: @codedme `display: inline-block` also establishes a BFC, but I didn't use it because of the ["extra space below" problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5804256/1529630), which would need `vertical-align`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.div1{
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background-color:red;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}   
.div2{
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background-color:green;
    display:block;
    float:left;

}
.div3{
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background-color:yellow;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear: both; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

This will do what you want, but, there is much to improve in that code to make it more simple and more DRY, this will be a short answer, if you want to see a better and smaller style to do the same just ask, and gladly will help.

Comment: How to make this simple webpage even more simpler? I mean its just 3 squares

Comment: Not the page the code, for example if you see the 3 divs have almost the same properties, so if you create a clase square you can add there all your styles as height:40px;   width:40px;display:block; float:left; and the for each just add the colours and the clear. As I said before, just a suggestion to have smaller and readable code