# flexbox align item to specified baseline?

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

I would like to know if there is a way to override/specify a baseline when you are using flexbox and try to use `align-items: baseline`.

I have a flex container that holds a few different divs (i.e., title, img, body, description).

With these flex items, I would like to center on a baseline of a div with `.flex-body`. It should center on the underline of the 'center here' text.

This is what my current attempt is producing.

[image]

I would like it to look like this, where each row has the flex items centered on the "center here" underline --- not perfectly lined up because I was just sticking margins in there to get the picture to kind of look like what I wanted :P

[image]

If align items to baseline is what I need, how can I use it to center my flex divs to the underline in the middle of the item?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/NickDueber-minted/pen/XKvBmz)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.flex-img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-title">
      flex title1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body">
      center here
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body-more">
      more text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-title">
      flex title1 longer title

    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body">
      center here
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body-more">
      more text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-title">
      flex title1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x90/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body">
      center here
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body-more">
      more text more text more text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-title">
      flex title1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body">
      center here
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body-more">
      more text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-title">
      flex title1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x50/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body">
      center here
    </div>
    <div class="flex-body-more">
      more text
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can:

- Wrap the contents of the flex items inside `inline-block`s

  That's because the [baseline](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) of an `inline-block` is in a very interesting position:

  > The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
  >   in the normal flow

  ```html
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <!-- contents here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

  ```css
  .inner-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ```
- Float the contents after the desired baseline

  This way they will be ignored when calculating the baseline, because floats are [out-of-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23). This has some [sideway effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32301823/1529630), which are mitigated because the `inline-block` wrappers establish a block formatting context.

  If you have multiple of them, you can clear them or use `width: 100%` to prevent them from stacking horizontally.

  ```css
  .flex-body-more {
    float: left; /* Take out-of-flow */
    clear: left; /* Do not stack horizontally */
    width: 100%; /* Do not shrink-to-fit */
  }
  ```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.inner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.flex-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.flex-body-more {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1 longer title</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x90/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text more text more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x50/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliantly convoluted! Flexbox, floats and `inline-block` all in one place. And actually using the most deeply buried spec language (the actual last line, in fact) for `inline-block` baseline alignment. Finally, somebody calls that into service :-) Nice work.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks :) Having different baselines for different kinds of boxes makes it difficult for the CSS WG to standardize something coherent in CSS align, but allows some nice tricks like that.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have been hitting my head against the wall with this problem for the past couple of days :)

Comment: I have seen an issue with both of our approches, you need to have text at the end of the baseline, no images

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Oriol's answer, I came up with an approach that doesn't require the float property. I don't consider myself a pro at CSS, so it could have other issues, but I think this solution is a bit simpler as it does not use float.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.w-full {  width: 100% }
.baseline {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.border-b {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.flex-img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="baseline w-full border-b">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
    </div>
    <div>more text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="baseline w-full border-b">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1 longer title</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
    </div>
    <div>more text</div>
    <div>more text</div>
    <div class="w-full">
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="baseline w-full border-b">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x90/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
    </div>
    <div>more text more text more text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="baseline w-full border-b">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
    </div>
    <div>more text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="baseline w-full border-b">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x50/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      center here
    </div>
    <div>more text1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv2gjt1d/17/)