# Is it correct to use float:left and clear:both in same DIV?

Tags: html, css

Is there something technically incorrect about floating and clearing in a single DIV?  For example `float:left` begins a box formatting context and `clear:both` ends a box formatting context.  Placing both in a single `DIV` appears to create a self contained BFC not unlike `overflow:hidden`.

Here is a simple example:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

I tested this in every modern browser except Safari because I don't have an iPhone handy.  I also tested it in IE8 through 11.  In all cases it worked perfect.  In addition it validated properly on [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net).  But I wonder if I'm missing something.  If this is proper and if it works why do so many people use the [clearfix hack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)? Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. Floating takes the element out-of-flow in a special way, and clearing pushes the element below previous floats.

This is not a replacement of the clearfix hack because a cleared float is still out-of-flow, and thus the parent element won't grow to encompass it (unless it establishes a block formatting context). See [Floating elements within a div, floats outside of div. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2062258/1529630) for more information.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
span {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  background: yellow;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
No clearfix:
<div>
  <span>Float</span>
  <span>Float</span>
  Text
</div>
With clearfix:
<div class="clearfix">
  <span>Float</span>
  <span>Float</span>
  Text
</div>
```

Comment: You might bold the "previous floats" part. I'm betting some think that really is a substitute.

Comment: I'm dissecting your amazingly helpful comment in [Floating elements within a div, floats outside of div. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062258/floating-elements-within-a-div-floats-outside-of-div-why).  I plan to spend the rest of the day (and possibly much of tomorrow) tearing apart your examples in Dreamweaver.  I'm going to fully understand this before I move on.  The basics of float and clear are easy but understanding the root fundamentals is mind-boggling.