# Div with margin: 0 auto preventing another Div from floating to the right of it

Tags: css

I'm trying to get div `#primary` to sit in the middle of the page with `position: relative` and `margin: 0 auto`, and I also want to have an `<aside>` element that sits directly to the right of `#primary` and does not shift around on width resize.

With `margin: 0 auto`, I notice in Chrome/Firefox Developer Tools that this effectively gives `#primary` full margins on either side, preventing anything from entering that space.

I tried giving `#primary` `float: left`, but this seems to cancel out the `margin: 0 auto` and makes `#primary` flush against the left side of the page.

How can I achieve this effect? Thanks.

```css
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#primary {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

aside {
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <div id="primary"></div>

  <aside></aside>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place `aside` *above/before* that centered DIV in your HTML code (I changed the dimensions of the elements to make it fit into the snippet window):

```css
#content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: yellow;
}

#primary{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}

aside {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <aside>aside</aside>

    <div id="primary">primary</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this as the correct answer when it lets me...why does this work though?

Comment: because `float: right` means that other elements can float around it (text) or next to it (blocks) at the left side - but beginning at its position in the code, not before that (i.e. it will not move up even if there is space)

Comment: Cool, thanks. I guess it takes it out of the flow? Found this answer helpful, too https://stackoverflow.com/a/32301823/7386637