# Image goes out from the div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a `<section>` and inside there is text and an image. I give a background to the section but don´t apply to the image. The image has bootstrap class. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```html
<section class="about">
    <h2>Title here</h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQH92_pzwQHHGA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0?e=1529355600&v=beta&t=8VBme0P0e-CIprWjJzI15iFhkJsSl9SbfdKmzABs3Pc" class="rounded float-right">
</section>
```

Comment: <section class="about">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQH92_pzwQHHGA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0?e=1529355600&v=beta&t=8VBme0P0e-CIprWjJzI15iFhkJsSl9SbfdKmzABs3Pc" class="rounded float-right">
</section>

Comment: Can you provide your css code?

Comment: .navigation{
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color:blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.navigation a {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  
}

.about{
  background:red;
}

Comment: Maybe you can try do add `overflow: hidden;` in your about class in css.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating elements within a div, floats outside of div. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062258/floating-elements-within-a-div-floats-outside-of-div-why)

Answer (score 0):

You need `overflow: hidden;` in your about class.

```
.about {
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```