# Create Printable Newspaper-like two column layout using Foundation 6 for Sites

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am looking for some guidance regarding how to create a printable newspaper-like layout using Foundation for sites. In plain CSS I can use css columns to create a two column layout where content from column 1 flows into column 2 when it needs to. I have tried using this in conjunction with Foundation for sites and it looks great on the webpage, but when I try to print the content breaks out of the columns. I am new to Foundation and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Hi Allison. Can you share your current layout? There will be maybe `grid-container`, `grid-x` and `cell` from [doc](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/xy-grid.html). But the issue with the floating is not that easy.

Comment: @KargWare -  I used a print container with the css of `-webkit-columns: 2 200px;
    -moz-columns: 2 200px;
    columns: 2 200px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;` and the foundation code as `<div class='grid-x grid-padding-x'>
<div class = 'cell medium-9'> 
<h4 >$billNum $title $title2<span> ($firstname $midname $lastname)</h4>
<h5 >Synopsis:</h5><p><pre >$synopsis</pre></p>
</div>
<div class = 'cell medium-3'>
<div class='card'>
"<div class='card-section'>
<span >Position: $position </span>
</div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>  `

Comment: @KargWare, I think the card and the two cells inside the grid-x maybe causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this here, btw. you can do it w/o Foundation as well. But you mentioned it, so create a XY-Grid and but ONE `cell` inside, with `auto` to width of 100%.

The layout with ZURB Foundation

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x">
        <div class="cell auto">

        <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
        <div class="outer">Lorem ipsum (even more)</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `style.css`

```css
.outer {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.inner {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #77a8b8ab;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The `50%` forces the two columns, maybe use a breakpoint on mobile first / small devices to jump back to 100%.

My post was inspirated from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2062258/10655742)

Comment: Going to one cell inside the grid-x seems to work, coupling that with column: 2; designation in CSS is keeping the content from breaking out in print mode. I could not use the 2 div process you outlined since I am putting dynamic content in the div. I appreciate the help.